# Async WCF call with monodroid

Tags: xamarin.android

My current method of making a call to WCF is the bog standard event, async style (for example)

```
foo.EventArgs += Foo_EventArgsCompleted
foo.EventArgsAsync(params...)
```

this works fine, but is hideously slow sometimes and is also cumbersome as you then need another method to deal with the results.

Is there a way to code this closer to the way it's done on Win8?

```
private async foo<bool>()
{
  try 
  {
     await foo.EventArgsAsync(params...)
  } 
  catch
  {
     // catch here
  }

  // deal with the code back
  return true;
}
```

Thanks

Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [write your own `*TaskAsync` extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873178.aspx).

If your proxy has `*Begin`/`*End` methods, you can use `TaskFactory.FromAsync`:

```
public static Task<int> FooTaskAsync(this FooClient client)
{
  return Task<int>.Factory.FromAsync(client.BeginFoo, client.EndFoo, null);
}
```

Otherwise, you have to use `TaskCompletionSource`:

```
public Task<int> FooTaskAsync(this FooClient client)
{
  var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();
  client.FooCompleted += (s, e) =>
  {
    if (e.Error != null) tcs.SetException(e.Error);
    else if (e.Cancelled) tcs.SetCanceled();
    else tcs.SetResult(e.Result);
  };
  client.FooAsync();
  return tcs.Task;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Will this have any great speed difference over the way I originally had it?

Comment: No. You're wrapping one asynchronous API with another; if anything, it will be a tiny bit slower. The upside is that `Task`-based APIs can be used seamlessly with `async`, so your code is much cleaner.